# Jquery find text in a td after current td

Tags: jquery

I'm using Jquery (Coffeescript) in a Rails 3.2 app. In a form, I want to add some checks using Jquery.

If the user changes the value of a  containing class 'numeric', I want to check the input he has typed into the next  of class 'text'. I'm just debugging right now.  I can't get the content of the next `text` field.

This is the HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td class="strongnowrap">Construction Costs</td>
  <td class="typical"></td>
  <td class="typical_dollars"></td>
  <td class="calculated"></td>
  <td class="amount"><div class="control-group integer optional costproject_costestimates_amount"><div class="controls"><input class="numeric integer optional" id="costproject_costestimates_attributes_0_amount" name="costproject[costestimates_attributes][0][amount]" style="width:100px" type="text" value="120000"></div></div></td>
  <td>
  <a rel="popover" data-content="Estimated cost for Contractor to construct the project" data-original-title="" title=""><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
 </td>
 <td class="note"><div class="control-group text optional costproject_costestimates_notes"><div class="controls"><textarea class="text optional" cols="40" id="costproject_costestimates_attributes_0_notes" name="costproject[costestimates_attributes][0][notes]" rows="1" style="width:150px">To Improve the Looks</textarea></div></div></td>
</tr>
```

This is the code I'm trying:

```
$('.numeric').change ->
  note = $(this).next().find('.text').html()
  I thought note = 'To Improve the Looks'
  **OR - I tried a test to see if empty**
  $(this).closest('tr').next('.text').is(":empty")
```

I get 'undefined' errors.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.text').is(":empty")
```

`.find` will all the children (and their children) of the `tr` - `next` simply looks at the very next element, and that didnt have class `.text` - so it was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for .nextAll();

https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Answer (score 0):

[`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
  note = $(this).parents('tr').find('.text').html()
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/cw0cbqL1/1/**